# PhpMyAdmin Database Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I got the following error when I tried to import my script's DB table structure.

Error
SQL query:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `characters`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `characters` (

 `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `tag_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `anime_title_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `role` VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,
 `first_name` VARCHAR( 512 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
 `last_name` VARCHAR( 512 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
 `japanese_name` VARCHAR( 512 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
 `description` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
 `source_link` VARCHAR( 512 ) NOT NULL ,
 `date_updated` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
 `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT =133870 DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> `#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

Comment: I'd say the error is quite clear. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: I mean how to clear the following error?

Comment: Which one would be better, TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT for date_created' or 'date_updated'?

Comment: One would have to know *a lot* more about the intended use of the table to answer that.

Comment: Read your code, that help a lot. Let me help, the error says `there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause` that means you should have only ONE timestamp column with the default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so change one or more columns type from `TIMESTAMP` to `DATETIME` or remove the default value of date_updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have mysql version less than `5.6.5`, and prior that

> At most one TIMESTAMP column per table could be automatically
>   initialized or updated to the current date and time.

So the error message is clear you can not have more than one timestamps value with auto update.

Upgrade the mysql to latest version to get rid of this error.

Comment: I can't update, Its my GoDaddy's Shared Hosting MySql Version. Is there anyother alternate way to do this?

Comment: No in that case you have to have only one column with `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and the other needs to be updated via application level, may be you keep it for `date_updated` and while adding a new entry add the value manually inside the insert query.

Answer (score 0):

Change the any one of the timestamps to datetime property.then insert all import values.. Once successfully inserted all data values into table change date time property  to timestamp. Here after application level its working fine.